# UITextfield having strange effect

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm working on presenting a textfield with background color on a white white picture, however, I constently get something like this [image: strange effect]

The code I used to add the background picture and the textfield is like this

```
    var textFieldBackground = UIImageView()
    var textField = UITextField()

    textFieldBackground.image = UIImage(named: "textFieldBackground")
    textFieldBackground.frame.size.width = 3.0
    textFieldBackground.frame.size.height = 1.75
    textFieldBackground.center.x = view.center.x
    textFieldBackground.center.y = view.center.y + 120
    textFieldBackground.alpha = 0.00

    textField.text = "Enter your name"
    textField.frame.size.width = 2.5
    textField.frame.size.height = 0.5
    textField.center.x = view.center.x
    textField.center.y = view.center.y + 120
    textField.alpha = 0.00


UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay:3.0,usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0,options: [], animations: {
        self.view.addSubview(self.textFieldBackground)
        self.textFieldBackground.alpha += 1.0
        self.textFieldBackground.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(110, 110)

        self.view.addSubview(self.textField)
        self.textField.alpha += 1.0
        self.textField.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(110, 110)

        }, completion: nil)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can I have the textfield with only one specific color? cuz I tried and it's like from white to black

Comment: How about `textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't you try this:

```
self.TextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
```

or you may do this in Interface builder. As most of views it has some kind of similar interface for changing the way it looks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Good chance your issue is with this line (used twice):

```
CGAffineTransformMakeScale(110, 110)
```

The parameters should be less than 1.0 to shrink the object, and greater than 1.0 to make the object larger. 110 makes it 110 times larger than the original. So you're likely stretching the image so you only see the first couple of pixels stretched out, giving you the effect you see. Try changing to 1.1 to only make it a little larger. Without seeing your actual image, that's just a guess at what you're trying to achieve.

Also, change this: `alpha += 1.0` to `alpha = 1.0`. Alpha should only be a value between 0.0 and 1.0, so adding 1.0 to whatever it was before could make it larger than 1.0 and give you unintended side effects (most likely issues when trying to make it transparent again).

Yet another also: Move this line `self.view.addSubview(self.textFieldBackground)` out of the animation closure. Add the view (it's transparent because the alpha is 0) before the closure as the actual adding of the view is not an animatable action.